# Feature rescaling for k-means clustering

Tags: k-means, feature-scaling

Is it correct to only rescale a large int feature and leave the % features as is when running k-means algorithm for segmentation analysis ?

e.g. a feature is the population of the city(150 000), then the rest features are % (e.g. 0.46) of energy consumption etc etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21222/are-mean-normalization-and-feature-scaling-needed-for-k-means-clustering ?

Comment: I've actually read that thread prior to posting this.to my mind the difference of this post is whether it's appropriate to only rescale one of them rather than both continuous variables/features.

Comment: I think the best answer is to `test` and `evaluate` with the change and without the change.